¿Cómo puedo enviar datos con post, pero usando valor desde un textbox de un formulario?
Necesito enviar enviar datos vía post a una URL específica. Si escribo todos los valores desde el código, me funciona bien, pero necesito enviar el "dato" desde un textbox del formulario. No logro hacer que me tome la variable desde el TextBox.
Estoy usando Visual Basic desde Visual Studio.
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim restClient = "https://SITIOWEB/rest/executetransaction"
        Dim client = New RestClient With {
            .BaseUrl = New Uri(restClient)
        }
        Dim request = New RestRequest()
        Dim t = TextBox1.Text
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
        request.Method = Method.POST
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "{" & vbCrLf &
                             """identification"":{" & vbCrLf &
                             """Password"": ""CLAVE""," & vbCrLf &
                             """UserName"": ""USUARIO""" & vbCrLf &
                             "}," & vbCrLf &
                             """request"":{" & vbCrLf &
                             """transactionType"":""TRX""," & vbCrLf &
                             """terminalId"":""dato""," & vbCrLf &
                             "}" & vbCrLf &
                             "}", ParameterType.RequestBody)
        Dim response = client.Execute(request).Content.ToString()
        MessageBox.Show(response)
    End Sub


realmente no entiendo tu problema.. tomarlo de una variable, o de un textbox, es lo mismo.. tu textbox, es una variable.. es un objeto que tiene la capacidad de ser "visible" en un formulario.. y los datos los tomas como tomas los datos de cualquier textbox para cualquier cosa.. usualmente estan en textbox.text (o value, dependiendo de tu framework de vista)... tal vez, deberias estudiar como funcionan los forms (no se que estes usando, si wpf o winforms o maui o que) para que veas que no importa que se dibujen o no, son objetos...

Saludos, gracias, lo que no logro hacer es que ese valor "dato" me lo lea de una variable, aqui estoy leyendo el textbox 'Dim t = TextBox1.Text', pero no encuentro como reconocer el valor de "t" dentro del Json.

o sea.. no sabes concatenar strings??? sigo sin entender tu pregunta, o tal vez no te estas explicando bien, porque ahi concatenaste strings...

Gracias, no se como hacer me tome el valor de la variable "t" en sustiticion de "dato".  Si lo hago asi '"""terminalId"": & t &," & vbCrLf &' el valor de t no lo toma.

Lo que señalas, es imposible.. si concatenas la t, deberia tomarlo.. por favor, usa el boton [edit] y agrega como lo estas intentando.. porque en eso que pusiste ahi sobran , y : y es muy probable que sea por eso...

entendes como concatenar strings?? leiste al respecto??? las variables van por fuera de los strings, salvo que uses interpolacion de cadenas...
